# React-big-calendar Show only current month and next month

Tags: javascript, reactjs, momentjs, react-big-calendar

How can I display only current month and next month using react big calendar and make it change dynamically every day?

I have a component that looks like this:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import 'react-big-calendar/lib/css/react-big-calendar.css'
import BigCalendar from 'react-big-calendar';
import moment from 'moment';
import 'moment/locale/pl';


class NewCalendar extends Component {
    constructor(props, context) {
        super(props, context);
        BigCalendar.momentLocalizer(moment);

    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div {...this.props}>
                <BigCalendar
                    messages={{next: "Następny", previous: "Poprzedni", today: "Dzisiaj", month: "Miesiąc", week: "Tydzień"}}
                    culture='pl-PL'
                    timeslots={1}
                    events={[]}
                    views={['month', 'week', 'day']}
                    min={new Date('2017, 1, 7, 08:00')}
                    max={new Date('2017, 1, 7, 20:00')}
                />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
export default NewCalendar;
```

But it only show minimum and maximum hours from 8AM to 8PM, how to set max and min to days?

Comment: Im not seeing anything about that, have you tried passing days only with no hours?

Comment: I tried but then it displays every day of calendar and it seens that doesn't work. Whats more I Need this hours limits so I can't delete it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've done some research and found a little inspiration for a hack here:
there doesn't seem to be anything readily available like `minDate` or `maxDate`. But there's a prop called `date` which is an instance of JS `Date()`. And `date` decides the visible calendar range.
There's another prop called `onNavigate` of type `function`.
So you should make sure your state has an initial key-value pair like:

```
{
    dayChosen: new Date() //just initalize as current moment
}
```

Then as two props for `MyCalendar` component you can write:

```
date={this.state.dayChosen}

onNavigate={(focusDate, flipUnit, prevOrNext) => {
    console.log("what are the 3 params focusDate, flipUnit, prevOrNext ?", focusDate, flipUnit, prevOrNext);


const _this = this;

const now = new Date();
const nowNum = now.getDate();
const nextWeekToday = moment().add(7, "day").toDate();
//I imported `moment.js` earlier

const nextWeekTodayNum = nextWeekToday.getDate();

  if (prevOrNext === "NEXT" 
      && _this.state.dayChosen.getDate() === nowNum){
        _this.setState({
          dayChosen: nextWeekToday
        });
  } else if (prevOrNext === "PREV" 
  && _this.state.dayChosen.getDate() === nextWeekTodayNum){
    _this.setState({
      dayChosen: now
    });
  }
}}
```

In my example, user can click the buttons `back` and `next` but I have successfully restricted the calendar to only show `this week` and `the following week`. User cannot view `previous weeks` or `more than 1 week down the road`. If you want `monthly restriction` instead of `weekly`, you can change the logic easily.

Answer (score 1):

I don't quite understand your entire question.

But if you want to hide away days that fall outside the current month, you can do it with css

```html
.rbc-off-range {
    /* color: #999999; */
    color: transparent;
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

Please see attached.

If you want to dynamical display the date, just pass in a date that's a javascript date string.

```js
<BigCalendar
  {...allYourProps}
  date={new Date('9-8-1990')
        /*evaluates to 'Sat Sep 08 1990 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (EDT)'*/
       }
/>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IxY4z.png)